# Sorting data elements and displaying with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a sql table 'sample' with 3 fields id,content, arrange. The field arrange gives the order to be displayed contents in html page.

```
 --------------------
 id|content|arrange
 --------------------
 1   A        4
 2   B        5
 3   C        1
 4   D        3
 5   E        2
-------------------
```

When use the query

```
SELECT content FROM sample order by arrange
```

gives me result in the order

```
 ----
 C
 E
 D
 A
 B
 ----
```

My question is how we can change the positions and update it in Database?

For example I need to move value 'A' to position of 'C', and all other contents should be relatively updated.

how can we do that?

Comment: Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: SELECT content FROM sample order by arrange will arrange recordset .    it will never gives result as you given.

Comment: I'm taking the values of table 'sample' to display content based on arrange field value.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT content , @i := @i +1 AS NewOrder
FROM sample
order by arrange
```

in PHP, read `dr['NewOrder']` and update it to db?